# How can I call Iterator .map() with a function that can fail?

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm using this code:

```rust
let players: Vec<Player> = players_to_create
    .iter()
    .map(|o| Player::new(&o.id, &o.team_id, &o.name)?)
    .collect();
```

but I'm geting this error:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/main.rs:17:57
   |
17 |         .map(|o| Player::new(&o.id, &o.team_id, &o.name)?)
   |              ---                                        ^ cannot use the `?` operator in a closure that returns `Player`
   |              |
   |              this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, ()>>` is not implemented for `Player`
```

If I remove the `?` I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<Player>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `Result<Player, ()>`
  --> src/main.rs:15:32
   |
15 |       let players: Vec<Player> = players_to_create
   |  ________________________________^
16 | |         .iter()
17 | |         .map(|o| Player::new(&o.id, &o.team_id, &o.name))
   | |_________________________________________________________^ value of type `Vec<Player>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=Result<Player, ()>>`
18 |           .collect();
   |            ------- required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `FromIterator<Result<Player, ()>>` is not implemented for `Vec<Player>`
   = help: the trait `FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `Vec<T>`
note: required by a bound in `collect`
```

Can you help me understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) to convert the `Result`s to `Option`s. Then you have an `Iterator<Item = Option<Player>>` which can be collected directly into an `Option<Vec<Player>>`:

```
players = 
    players_to_create
    .iter()
    .map(|o| Player::new(&o.id, &o.team_id, &o.name).ok())
    .collect();
```

Or you can change the type of `player` to `Result<Vec<Player>, ???>` (replacing `???` with the actual error type) and collect directly to that instead:

```
let players: Result<Vec<Player>, _> =
    players_to_create
    .iter()
    .map(|o| Player::new(&o.id, &o.team_id, &o.name))
    .collect();
```

Comment: One subtle detail to be aware of: using `collect` in this way short-circuits, so it will stop iterating after the first `Err`/`None`.